# Integer linear constraint(s) for y= x1 XOR x2

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, integer-programming, mathematical-modeling

Is there any way to convert $y=x_1~ \text{XOR} ~x_2$ to  linear constraints? It means we write some  linear relations with:

if $x_1=x_2 =0$ or $x_1=x_2=1$ $\to$ $y=0$,
else, $y=1$?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean XOR? By the truth table you should have something like: `y=x1+x2-2*t` where `t` is additional variable.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it.

Comment: In fact, $t=x_1 \times x_2$. It seems this nonlinear relation must also be considered and converted to a linear relation.  Is it necessary?

Answer (score 2):

You can derive the desired constraints somewhat automatically via conjunctive normal form as follows:
$$(\lnot x_1 \land \lnot x_2) \implies \lnot y \\
\lnot (\lnot x_1 \land \lnot x_2) \lor \lnot y \\
(x_1 \lor x_2) \lor \lnot y \\
x_1 + x_2 + (1-y)\ge 1\\
x_1 + x_2 -y \ge 0
$$
The other three constraints are similar.

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the cube $0 \le x_1, x_2, y \le 1$ then the eight possible Boolean assignments to $x_1, x_2, y$ are the vertices of the cube. We can mark an assignment $x_1 = a, x_2 = b, y = c$ as illegal with the constraint $$\begin{pmatrix}x_1 - \tfrac12 \\ x_2 - \tfrac12 \\ y - \tfrac12\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}a - \tfrac12 \\ b - \tfrac12 \\ c - \tfrac12\end{pmatrix} < \begin{pmatrix}a - \tfrac12 \\ b - \tfrac12 \\ c - \tfrac12\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}a - \tfrac12 \\ b - \tfrac12 \\ c - \tfrac12\end{pmatrix}$$

which can be expressed as a linear constraint with integer coefficients via suitable scaling. The xor constraint can be written as four of these linear constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Under the constraints $x_1,x_2,y\in\{0,1\}$, the equality $y=x_1\oplus x_2$ is equivalent to
$$\begin{cases}
y \geq x_1 - x_2, \\
y \geq x_2 - x_1, \\
y \leq x_1 + x_2, \\
y \leq 2 - x_1 - x_2.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: A more symmetric form: $x_3=x_1\oplus x_2$ is equivalent to $x_1+x_2+x_3\le2$ and $x_i\le x_j+x_k$ for $\{i,j,k\}=\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Yes, and more symmetric initial equation is $x_1\oplus x_2\oplus x_3 = 0$.

Comment: Isn't it more elementary to observe that XOR is addition modulo 2 and introduce a temporary variable and the constraint $y=x_1+x_2-2 t,0 \le y \le 1$?

Comment: @joro: It depends on relative cost of variables vs constraints. It is often believed that introducing new variables results in a more computationally costly ILP problem, and from this perspective 4 constraints are more preferable than 1 constraint and 1 variable.